# Chrome and Safari not accepting Blobs as Script src arguments

Tags: google-chrome, safari, http-status-code-404, blob

I've been doing my includes a new way lately, that's helped a lot with debugging, but I recently found that it only works in Firefox.

An example of the code is below.  When run on Firefox, "Hello World" is alerted.  When run in Safari and Chrome, a 404 for the blob arises.  This code does not do the same thing in a snippet as it does in an html file, so I've included the plaintext below.

```
<script>

function includeScript(script) {

  var file = new Blob([script], {
    type: "text/javascript"
  });
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);

  var addMe = document.createElement("script");
  addMe.src = url + "?test";
  addMe.type = "text/javascript";

  document.head.appendChild(addMe);
}

function tryIt() {
  includeScript("alert('hey'); foo.bar");
}
</script>


<body>
  <button onclick="tryIt()">Try It</button>
</body>
```

Why do Chrome and Safari return 404's for blobs, and is there a way for me to get around it?

I've made sure that local strict_orgin_policy is enabled on Firefox, and it still works, so I don't think it's a local resource issue.  Also, blobs can work fine if done in console in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

As it ends up, Chrome and Safari can both load blobs, but they can not have a question mark at the end with url arguments.

This will work:

```
<script src="blob:123123123123">
```

This will not

```
<script src="blob:123123123123?arg1=hat">
```